# Obtaining the inequality$\frac{C}{2^{m-1}-1}(2+\log(2^{m-1}-1))\le \frac{Cm}{2^m}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

I'm looking at a proof for obtaining an inequality and in the final line there is this inequality.

$$\frac{C}{2^{m-1}-1}(2+\log(2^{m-1}-1))\le \frac{Cm}{2^m}$$ where $C$ is some constant and $m\in \mathbb{N}$. I can't figure out how to show this inequality. I would greatly appreciate any help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What constraints are there on $C$? Is it positive?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen yes positive

Comment: Then I think your inequality is backwards

Comment: I don't think the inequality holds when $C$ is positive. In that case, for large positive $m$, $\frac{C}{2^{m-1}-1}(2 + \log(2^{m-1}-1)) \approx \frac{C}{2^{m-1}}(1+m) \ge \frac{Cm}{2^m}$.

Comment: @NilabroSaha exactly. I think the OP has this backwards. Of course, even then some weird stuff happens for small $m$. The inequality is more of a thing just for large $m$, as you note

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I uploaded the proof where I got this inequality from and I need this bound for the bottom proof in obtaining a contradiction. Can you perhaps tell me where this proof goes wrong?

Comment: The inequality clearly doesn't apply for $m=1$. Graphing the LHS and RHS seems to suggest that the inequality in its present form, with $C$ positive, doesn't hold for any $m\in \Bbb{N} -{1}$.

Comment: Of course, the reverse inequality does hold, judging from the graphs.

Comment: @NilabroSaha I can confirm that your analysis of the graphs is correct from doing some algebra on the inequality. We can write it as $$\frac{4+2\ln \left(x-1\right)}{1+\log _2\left(x\right)} \le  \frac{x-1}{2x}$$ which is clearly false by taking limits.

Comment: In fact, for all $x>3$ we have that the LHS is monotonically decreasing toward $2\ln(2)$ and the RHS is moronically increasing toward $1/2$.

Comment: Yes that's what I noticed. Moreover, the graphs seemed to me like the Maxwellian distribution.

Comment: I know this is severely deviating from the question, but is there a reason why the graphs look like the Maxwellian distribution. I actually don't know the equation for the distribution, so maybe the LHS and the RHS resemble it?